# How to clear ext4 filesystem of partition in arch

Tags: linux, arch-linux, ext4, mkfs

I'm installing Arch Linux by guide and misinterpreted some stuff about installing the bootloader. Therefore I went back and cleared my `/dev/sdb` partitions. Before that I made `sdb1` as linux filesystem (8300) and `sdb2` as swap partition (8200).

To delete partitions I used `gdisk` and the `d` command to remove the partitions.
Running `lsblk` showed be that `sdb` is only a disk without partitions now.

Then I created new partitions with `gdisk` again. After I created them I want to mount a filesystem `ext4` to `sdb1` by executing `mkfs.ext4 -L arch /dev/sdb1`

Following warning appears `/dev/sdb1 contains a ext4 file system labelled 'arch'`.
And telling me the date and time when I did so.

How can I actually clear the partitions without having such things still left? It seems that I did not really *format* the partitions

Comment: If you are happy to use the command line, dd will do the job for you.

Comment: I am happy with that. I kinda found out that overwriting the old fs does no harm

Answer (score 10):

The command you want is `wipefs -a`.  When deleting partitions that you have no intent of recovering data from, run this on each partition prior to deleting it.  In this particular case however, you can probably just pass `-f` to the `mkfs` command you're trying to run on that partition, and it will ignore what's there and create a new filesystem (don't get in the habit of doing this though, `mkfs` has this check intentionally so that you don't accidentally nuke a filesystem you actually need).

What's happened here is that you created the new partition at the same starting point the old partition was at.  Deleting a partition from the partition table doesn't delete any data in the region of the storage device that the partition delimited, it just means the OS stops treating that region as in use.  As a result, at least the first superblock from the old filesystem is still there and being seen by the tools, which assume there's a filesystem there as a safety precaution.

EDIT: As of (07-Jan-2020) using the mkfs command will prompt you if another fs exists on the partition.

```
jake@finn:~-$ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/ethereum/docker
mke2fs 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
/dev/ethereum/docker contains a bfs file system
Proceed anyway? (y,N) y
Discarding device blocks: done
```